# Django: manage.py standard commands not working

Tags: python, sql, database, django, command

I'm developing a web app in Python 2.7 using Django 1.4 with PyCharm 2.5 as my IDE and a Postgres database. I am able to run manage.py commands such as `sql` and `syncdb` to create the SQL and the tables, but other commands are not recognized. When I attempt to run `sqlreset` (or any other command that drops tables or alters data), I get an "Unknown command" error:

```
runnerw.exe C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2.5.1\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py" sqlreset EventMapperApp C:/Users/Karen/PycharmProjects/eventsMap
Unknown command: 'sqlreset'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a `sqlreset`.

Info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

or `manage.py help` as your post shows...

Comment: Best I can think of is there's `sqlsequencereset` and `sqlclear`

Comment: Oh! Well, that would make a lot of sense, wouldn't it! I guess PyCharm 's interface needs to be updated.

Comment: But there is a sqlreset in Django 1.4. It has been removed in development though.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are running Django 1.4? `sqlreset` has been deprecated since 1.3, I think, and is [slated to be removed in 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/internals/deprecation/#id3). [It is present in Django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#sqlreset-appname-appname), but has been removed in the development version.

Answer (score 0):

Django's management commands don't automatically run commands that may destroy your database (commands such as altering a table, or changing the type of columns).

If you want to completely reset your application - as if you just ran `syncdb`, you need to do it manually.

I wrote this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2704588) that will reset your database. It is not portable (only works on *inx-like systems), but it might help you out.

Note: this will delete (drop) everything.

```
echo 'from django.conf import settings; print settings.INSTALLED_APPS; quit();' | \
python manage.py shell --plain 2>&1 | \
tail -n1 | sed -r "s|^.*\((.*)\).*$|\1|; s|[',]| |g; s|django\.contrib\.||g" | \
xargs python manage.py sqlclear | \
python manage.py dbshell && python manage.py syncdb
```